# Angular 10 `routerLink` in` mat-tab` does not work

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink, mat-tab

I'm using Angular 10. In the `CoreModule` class I have the component `NavbarComponent`. I have this HTML template in the `NavbarComponent` component:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="end">
    <mat-tab routerLinkActive>Home</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab routerLink="/user/registration"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>Login</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

After clicking on the link, nothing happens. URL does not change. It's the same all the time `http://localhost:4200/home`.
In the class of the `HomeModule` module there is a component with an HTML template:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The `HomeRoutingModule` class contains arrays:

`const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }];`

The `AppRoutingModule` class contains arrays:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  { path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  },
];
```

The `UsersRoutingModule` class contains arrays:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'registration',
        data: { title: 'registration' },
        component: UserRegistrationComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

project structure:

[image]

I do not know how to make the redirection to the `UserRegistrationComponent` carried out. When I click:
`<mat-tab routerLink ="/user/registration ">`
URL does not change.

Please help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

related to your routes, this will work

```
<mat-tab routerLink="/user/user/registration"></mat-tab>
```

since you have

```
{ path: 'user',
 loadChildren: () => import('./modules/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)
},
```

so /user will load your lazy loaded module and then  the second /user

```
{
path: 'user',
component: UsersComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'registration',
    data: { title: 'registration' },
    component: UserRegistrationComponent,
  }
]
}
```

you can try change your users module routes like this

```
{
path: '',
component: UsersComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'registration',
    data: { title: 'registration' },
    component: UserRegistrationComponent,
  }
]
}
```

to make this work

```
<mat-tab routerLink="/user/registration"></mat-tab>
```

Comment: The URL still does not change :( I did as you wrote. In the `UsersRoutingModule` class I changed
`const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: UsersComponent, children: [{ path: 'registration', data: { title: 'registration' }, component: UserRegistrationComponent, }] }];`

and in the HTML template `<mat-tab routerLink="/user/registration"></mat-tab>` I still don't know how to improve the redirection to the UserRegistrationComponent

Answer (score 0):

Angular now provides [a different type of tab group](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation) for navigation, using a `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` element containing `<a mat-tab-link>` elements. The only caveat is that you need to manually provide
the `[active]` attribute.

For your example: (I assumed you meant to merge the second and third tabs)

```html
<!-- navbar.component.html -->
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link [active]="true">Home</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink='/user/registration'>Login</a>
</nav>
```